# Not able to open any site other than Stackexchange, Google and some others

Tags: networking, router, internet

I was using a DSL modem to connect to internet earlier, but recently I have bought a TP link wireless router which I am using now. For 2 days the router worked fine but today I am having some problems with Internet. I am able to open only some specific sites, like google or stackexchange but not other sites.

Also some sites open but only some part of them, for example this MIT OCW page.

[image: ocw half open page]

I am not a networking expert but I have still checked everything that I could.
So can you please tell me what should I do?

**EDIT:** As the problem is solved, there is no need to show the lengthy output of commands, so I have removed them.

Comment: First of all, `ping http://www.wolframalpha.com` is not how you ping wolframalpha.com. Try this command instead: `ping www.wolframalpha.com`

Comment: @Vinayak Now I am able to ping it but it is still not opening

Comment: Could you try changing your DNS settings to use OpenDNS (208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220) or GoogleDNS (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) and see if that helps?

Comment: @Vinayak Should I change primary or secondary dns?

Comment: You should change both (but take a note of your old DNS settings in case you use an ISP that requires you to log in to a captive portal before you use the Internet). You may follow the instructions here: [for Windows PCs](https://support.opendns.com/entries/36904770-Configuration-for-Windows-computers), [for routers](https://support.opendns.com/entries/27350174-Generalized-Router-Configuration-Instructions)

Comment: @Vinayak Nothing happened

Comment: do a traceroute for a domain that's blocked and post the results please. (e.g. `tracert www.wolframalpha.com`)

Comment: @Vinayak I addded 2 tracerts.

Comment: Can you visit the websites by directly visiting their IP address? (e.g. http://140.177.16.17)

Comment: @Vinayak Unfortunately, No, I cannot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16494/discussion-between-vinayak-and-kartik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I solved the problem.**

**The problem is with the default settings of the TP-link router.**

When we connect the router to a network, its default MTU is 1480. But (according to what i read on the net,) usually for PPPoE internet, it should be less than that. The solution is very simple, we have to go to 192.168.0.1 and go to `Network>Wan>Advanced Settings>MTU` and change it to 1460.

All the sites work now.